# Text hint vertically in EditText in Android?

Tags: android

Check This Image:

```
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cusumerName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:hint="Consumer Name"
                android:textColor="#660000"
                android:textSize="15sp" >
            </TextView>
```

Here I found Text hint on Top, I want it vertically, How can I do?

Comment: `android:gravity="center_vertical"`

Comment: `Check This Image` ... which Image?

Comment: You found text hint on Top, i want it vertically --> what does this even mean?

Comment: Why are you using hint with textview? you can use it with edittext, or if you just want simple text than user android:text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this in xml of TextView:

```
android:hint="H\ne\nl\nl\no"
```

Comment: "\n" will take text in next line